# Undefined opcodes for the Intel 8008 CPU

Tags: intel, microprocessor, 8008

What happens when I8008 CPU reads the "undefined" opcode (22h, 2Ah, 32h, 38h, 39h, 3Ah; or in octal 042, 052, 062, 070, 071, and 072)? Are these opcodes evaluated as a NOP instruction, or lead to some side effects (RESET, etc). How many T cycles those instruction takes?

Comment: Worth noting that almost all of these instructions are also undefined in the [Datapoint 2200](https://history-computer.com/Library/2200_Reference_Manual.pdf), which has the same instruction set architecture.  The only exception is 38h = 070, which is `PUSH` on the Datapoint.  There is no `PUSH` on the 8008, as the stack is on-chip instead of in memory.

Comment: Also, Ken Shirriff has done [several die analyses](https://www.righto.com/search/label/8008) of the 8008, but none that indicate what the undefined opcodes do.